# I am multiplying two matrix with lists. I expect answer in list format but getting in wrong format

Tags: list

```
m1=[]
m2=[]
ans=[]
tmp=[]
def matmult(m1,m2):
 sum1=c=d=k=0
 m=len(m1)
 n=len(m2)
 p=len(m1[0])
 q=len(m2[0])
 for c in range(0,m):
     for d in range (0,q):
         for k in range(0,p):
             sum1 = sum1 + m1[c][k]*m2[k][d]
             print sum1

         tmp.append(sum1)
         sum1=0
 ans.append(tmp)                   
 return ans
matmult([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]])
```

I expect answer in this format 
[[14, 32], [32, 77]]
but i am getting [[14, 32, 32, 77]].
Kindly help

Comment: Is this python? Either way a language tag will help